# Como faço um tratamento das opções do JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()?

Tags: java, swing, gui

Como faço para tratar as escolhas do usuário no `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`?
Por exemplo, quando o usuário escolhe *ok* o programa continua normalmente, caso ele escolha *cancelar* o programa executa outra linha de código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve usar `showConfirmDialog()` já que `showMessageDialog()` não retorna nada.

O `showConfirmDialog()` retorna um int, armazene-o e em seguida compare-o com as constantes estáticas da classe `JOptionPane`. Exemplo:

```
int i = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
        null, 
        "Deseja continuar?"
        );
if(i == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Clicou em Sim");
}
else if(i == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Clicou em Não");
}
else if(i == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Clicou em Cancel");
}
```

Resultado:

[image: selecionar]

Para alterar os botões do seu dialog, crie a versão sobrecarregada `showConfirmDialog(parentComponent, message, title, optionType)` onde `optionType` pode ser:

- DEFAULT_OPTION (apesar da documentação não deixar claro, é o OK sozinho)
- YES_NO_OPTION
- YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION
- OK_CANCEL_OPTION

Exemplo:

```
int i = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
        null, 
        "Deseja continuar?",
        "Continua",
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION
        );
```

Resultado:

[image: OkCancel]

Referência: [JOptionPane - Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)