# Confirmar fechamento de form

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Preciso perguntar se desejo fechar a janela que esta aberta. Fiz o seguinte form, mas em qualquer uma das opções, ele fecha. Atualmente utilizo essa opção de evento:

```
private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
    if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Você deseja realmente fechar essa janela? Todas mensagens serão perdidas") != JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) 
    {
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Esse é um segundo form, tenho o principal, com as opções e tenho esse que é o segundo, onde pergunto se deseja realmente fechar. Se trata de um JFrame.

Outro detalhe, é que na mensagem exibida existem 3 opções: SIM, NÃO e CANCELAR. Quero apenas as duas opções SIM e NÃO.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como faço um tratamento das opções do JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15061/3117)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando que o `segundo` se trata de um JFrame dentro do JFrame principal, o certo seria:

```
JFrame segundo = new JFrame();
segundo.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
// No método abaixo, diz que não é para fazer nada ao apertar receber o comando de fechar
segundo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
segundo.setVisible(true);
//sobrescreve o evento que é acionado quando se tenta fechar o JFrame
segundo.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        super.windowClosing(e);
        //pergunta para o usuário qual é a decisão dele
        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                null, 
                "Você deseja realmente fechar essa janela? "
                        + "Todas mensagens serão perdidas",
                        "Fechar",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION
                ) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            //caso deseja fechar, deixa torna invisível
            segundo.setVisible(false);
        }
        //não tem else pois o comportamento normal é DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE
    }
});
```

Comment: Inseri no código, mas quando clico em NÃO, ele fecha mesmo assim. O evento usado (windowClosing) está correto?

Comment: Na verdade eu uso sobrescrevo outro evento, deixa eu fazer um exemplo curto aqui pois eu não cheguei a compilar o código que eu postei acima.

Comment: Ok, aguardando. Só um detalhe: esse é um segundo form, tenho o principal, com as opções e tenho esse que é o segundo, onde pergunto se deseja realmente fechar.

Comment: Qual objeto é esse form? Um JFrame?

Comment: Sim, é um JFrame

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

A variável `evt` deve ter um propriedade `cancel` ou algo do tipo. Basta você setar como `true` caso o usuário não queria fechar que o fechamento será cancelado e você poderá ocultar o form.