# Dúvida - setDefaultCloseOperation

Tags: java, swing

Seria possível de algum modo passar para:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(UM METHODO?);
```

Ou utilizando alguma outra opção para fazer o mesmo procedimento?

O que acontece é que eu criei um botão e ele chama um "method" para ocultar o programa. Estou precisando que ao clicar no minimizar ele chame o "method" o mesmo método do botão para ocultar o programa ao lado do relógio.

Comment: O que pretendes fazer? podes explicar melhor?

Comment: Também não consegui entender o que precisa, se puder tentar elaborar melhor a sua pergunta seria bom. De qualquer forma dá uma olhada nessa pergunta que usa o mesmo método que você está citando: [Confirmar fechamento de form](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55940/3117) e veja se ajuda de alguma forma.

Comment: Certo vou ser mais claro. Criei 1 botão e ele chama um "method" para ocultar o programa. Estou precisando que ao clicar no minimizar ele chame o "method" o mesmo metodo do botão para ocultar o programa ao lado do relógio.

Comment: olha este link : http://www.landofcode.com/java-tutorials/java-events.php  verifica se não é nenhum deste métodos que precisas, mais especificamente `windowIconified`

Comment: @kholyphoenix1 transpus seu comentário para o corpo da pergunta, para ficar mais fácil para que for ler. Sinta-se a vontade para [edit] e mudar o que achar necessário.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve sobrescrever o método  [`windowIconified()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowIconified-java.awt.event.WindowEvent-), ele é invocado sempre que o frame for minimizado.

De acordo com a documentação:

> Invoked when a window is changed from a normal to a minimized state.

Esse método pertence à interface WindowListener, que é a interface que trata os eventos ocorridos com as janelas, como abrir, fechar, ativar, desativar, minimizar e restaurar.

Veja o exemplo:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Minimiza extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Minimiza frame = new Minimiza();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public Minimiza() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        //adicione esse trecho de código à sua classe
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowIconified(e);
                metodo(); //chama um método da sua classe
            }
        });
    }
    //método apenas de exemplo, pode implementar o que preferir aqui dentro
    public void metodo() {
        System.out.println("Método foi chamado");
    }
}
```

Comment: Certo consegui. Porém teve algo errado. o Method moveToTray pede para que seja "static" nisso eu aceito a correção no eclipse mais ao corrigir o icone não é mostrado mais. Também não consigo fazer com que ele ache o "frame". Tipo: frame.this.setVisible(true); ele diz que não é possível localizar a variavel.'

Comment: Com relação a achar o `frame` depende de como você criou seu form, se o `frame` é a sua classe principal que extende de JFrame, então para referenciá-lo basta fazer `this.setVisible(true)`, caso você tenha um objeto do tipo JFrame com uma variável de referência para ela, basta fazer `frame.setVisible(true)`, teria que ver qual é o seu caso. Sobre o primeiro erro, não consegui entender muito bem o que ocorreu, talvez seria o caso de criar uma pergunta nova, ou me explica de novo aqui pelos comentários para ver se dessa vez eu entendo.

Comment: O "Method" esta no final do frame. O main está asim: public class main extends JFrame {

Comment: Basta então dentro do "Method", se ele não for estático, fazer `this.setVisible(true)` ou `this.setVisible(false)`, apenas se atente para que você não crie uma condição onde seu form some para sempre, tem que fazer um jeito de o usuário mudar o status dele caso ele esteja invisível, pelo que eu entendi é isso.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e me desculpe o incomodo. Abraço!

Answer (score 3):

Não dessa forma. `setDefaultCloseOperation` recebe um inteiro correspondente a ação que deve ser tomada, por exemplo, para fechar o *frame* [`JFrame#EXIT_ON_CLOSE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#EXIT_ON_CLOSE) :

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

// é a mesma coisa que:
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
```

Você pode adicionar um [`WindowStateListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowStateListener.html) e através do método [`WindowEvent#getNewState`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html#getNewState%28%29) para obter o estado (minimizado, maximizado etc) atual do `JFrame`.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class MeuJFrame extends JFrame {

    public MeuJFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Adiciona o listener
        this.addWindowStateListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            // Quando houver uma mudança no estado da janela (lê-se seu JFrame)
            @Override
            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
                // Se o estado atual for minimizado, faz algo...
                if(Frame.ICONIFIED == e.getNewState()){
                    System.out.println("Chamando o método...");
                }
            } 
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MeuJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```